# O que compreende a região de memória alta (high memory area) , no DOS?

Tags: memória, sistema-operacional, ms-dos

Estou estudando sobre o gerenciamento de memória no DOS, e não encontrei muitas informações sobre o que exatamente está compreendido nesta área de memória. Abraço.

Comment: Renan, reabri sua pergunta, mas cinco pessoas consideraram que você está perguntando sobre como colocar um programa ou o próprio sistema operacional nessa região da memória. Nesse caso, seria uma dúvida sobre o uso do DOS, portanto não sobre programação e fora do escopo do site. Eu entendi que é uma pergunta conceitual sobre como o DOS organiza e usa a memória. Se for isso, você poderia por favor [edit] e complementar a pergunta com mais detalhes para que não haja risco de interpretações divergentes? Obrigado.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_memory_area 
Isso tem a ver com a limitaçao do 8086 (1Mb de RAM no maximo)

Comment: @Peter Um pouco mais interessante e no que respeita a programação, um desafio da altura ;)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96710